# Eclipse Error No Idea InterruptedException error

Tags: java, eclipse

I use the IDE eclipse everyday. Today it decided to not work for me, and I have work to do and really need it to.. If anyone could help, that'd be great.

When I startup eclipse it pops up an error message leading me to this error.

```
!SESSION 2016-05-14 09:11:04.108 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data C:\Users\STATION8\Desktop\Development\Minecraft\Tripex Development -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-05-14 09:35:37.423
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\STATION8'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-05-14 09:39:07.119
!MESSAGE Shutdown error
!STACK 1
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.waitForStop(SystemModule.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.waitForStop(EquinoxBundle.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.waitForStop(Equinox.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: I don't like that IDE, I've tried it.

Comment: Better than an IDE that doesn't work.  Too bad; your loss.